# 64-bit VM host environment for Debian similar to VMware player on Windows?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, 64-bit, debian, vmware-player

I have an Intel Core Duo i3-2100 running a flavour of Debian.

I understand Virtual Box is x86-only so is there any similar open source Virtualisation environment that can host images like VMware player on a Windows platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VirtualBox will work on a [64-bit Linux host](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads), and is able to virtualize both 32-bit and 64-bit clients as long as you enable the 64-bit client in BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

Virtualbox support 64-bit hosts and guests.

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox x86 only ?

You didn't even check the virtualbox website did you ?
That was many years ago.

These days you can even run a x64 guest on a x86 host as long as the host supports VT. 
(Which almost all modern CPU's do.)